# Kotlin idiomatic way to consume to a list

Tags: kotlin

Given a Kotlin function like this...

```
fun findAll(rowConsumer: (String) -> Unit) {
    ....
}
```

I can do this to produce a List...

```
val results = mutableListOf<String>()
someRef.findAll() { results.add(it) }
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin?
What about producing a Sequence instead of a List?

Comment: #1 You don't need the `()`. `someRef. findAll { }` #2 What is findAll supposed to even do? Its sounds like a filter of some sorts but for that you have `.filter`?. #3 If you want sequenece `.asSequence`?

Comment: Hi @TheLibrarian, this is a function to iterate over the result of a database query. The idea is to avoid a List, holding the full result set in memory, because we don't know how many rows it will return.

Comment: What are you trying to get out of this?  If want a list or other structure, you'd need to store it in memory as you say.  Or if you want to process the items one by one, you can just do it directly in the lambda.

Comment: Hi @gidds, I'm trying to write a function in a DAO class that is agnostic. For some callers of the DAO and for some queries, a List might be fine. For others it may lead to an OOME. Rather than forcing callers to provide a row consumer, it would be nicer if the DAO could just produce a Sequence.

Comment: Then... return a sequence? Or flow if you plan to use coroutines. I don't think such API as above could be easily transformed into a sequence. The problem is that it requires some thread to be occupied all the time in the `findAll()` function. So we would need at least two threads and somehow synchronize them.

Comment: If the `findAll` implementation is a given and won't change, then this is pretty much the best you can do. You could write it using a reference if you prefer: `someRef.findAll(results::add)`